How would i create a QEMU Machine that accepts multiple CPU options
I am working with the arm embedded toolchain  and have chosen to use QEMU as my simulated CPUs.
I use the -machine option currently to select from a for a family of arm processors on custom pcb boards, i have 3 types of board, each with a different arm core.
Each Arm core has a different memory address space which i want to select byhaving the board version text available within the qemu machine configuration code. By using the -cpu specifier, i believe it is possible to do what i want within the QEMU api.
So here is what i want to do, I currently have 3 machines (mymachineRevA, mymachineRevB, mymachineRevC) with the names of the board mashed in but i want to only use 1 machine (myarm) and specify the revision by using the cpu argument.
i want to do this ...
./qemu-system-arm -machine myarm -cpu RevA -kernel "myfile.img"
./qemu-system-arm -machine myarm -cpu RevB -kernel "myfile.img"
./qemu-system-arm -machine myarm -cpu RevC -kernel "myfile.img"
instead of this ...
./qemu-system-arm -machine mymachineRevA -kernel "myfile.img"
./qemu-system-arm -machine mymachineRevB -kernel "myfile.img"
./qemu-system-arm -machine mymachineRevC -kernel "myfile.img"
Please correct me if i'm wrong and there is an easier way to do this.
static void my_machine_class_init(ObjectClass *klass, void *data)
{
    MachineClass *mc = MACHINE_CLASS(klass);

    mc->desc = "ARM M Core (Cortex-M[33|85])";
    mc->ignore_memory_transaction_failures = true;
    mc->default_cpu_type = "RevA";
    mc->is_default = false;
    mc->default_ram_id = "reva.ram";
    mc->init = device_init;
    mc->max_cpus = 1;
};

static const TypeInfo arm_m_info = {
    .name = TYPE_MY_ARM_MACHINE,
    .parent = TYPE_MACHINE,
    .instance_size = sizeof(MYARMMachineState),
    .class_init = my_arm_machine_class_init,
};

At some point in my code i want to have the cpu available in the block below here.
static void arm_cpu_init(Object *obj)
{
    MYARMMachineState*s = MYARM_OBJ(obj);

    memory_region_init(&s->container, obj, "my_arm-container", UINT64_MAX);

    object_initialize_child(OBJECT(s), "armv8m", &s->arm_m, TYPE_ARMV7M);

    /* The mappings in cpu32.c apply here and it would lookup what revA / RevB etc cpu maps to in cpu32.c */
    qdev_prop_set_string(DEVICE(&s->arm_m), "cpu-type", cpu_name);
};


No, you can't do that (well, in theory it is possible but it's not the way that QEMU board models generally behave -- the -cpu option should only select the CPU, not do anything else; and the CPU argument has to be a valid CPU name, not an arbitrary string). You could use a machine property if you liked to specify the board revision: -machine myMachine,revision=A   vs -machine myMachine,revision=B.

If i specify revision on the command line, will i be able to parse that within the machine. And if so, would it do roughly what im looking for.
Assuming that if im only choosing between memory maps and keeping the cpu constant. (This i would say is the main goal of what im trying).
My side note guess is that, i if i do specify -cpu, is that handled elsewhere and i will never see the value passed or is it stored as a string somewhere?
qdev_prop_set_string(DEVICE(&s->arm_m), "cpu-type", cpu_name); <- sets the cpu yes? so surely qemu would want me to know what cpu to set.

The machine model code gets to parse machine options like that however it likes, yes. See eg how hw/arm/mps2-tz.c handles the "remap" property for an arbitrary-string example (or look for other board models calling object_class_property_add_str()).

That was fast. Ill have a look and see if what i'm trying to to can work with that, if not ill follow up. Thanks for that insight as i've been working on this for several months and it was a part of the machine model i couldn't quite grasp
